# Envoy access log stream to Logstash

Tags: logstash, envoyproxy

Envoy can stream access log out via gRPC. I'm trying to route Envoy access log to Logstash. I found a protobuf plugin here (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-protobuf.html) for Logstash. In it's config, it requires class_name and the files of pb.rb definitions. Look like to me that this is the proto file to use https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/3e63182c3e74e0d517d2f0d1fc2ee950bbfe21e1/api/envoy/data/accesslog/v2/accesslog.proto.? Apparently it depends on other definition files, e.g. envoy.api.v2.core.Address and some others. It's a deep dependency tree there. I'm not able to grep all the necessary proto files and compile them to Ruby. Anyone has such kind of experience connecting Envoy and Logstash?

Comment: Any luck with this? Any other methods used?